# Fixing dimnames(x) of xts objects in R via loop

Tags: r, xts

Assume I have a list of variables (class:xts) in `.GlobalEnv` identified as follows:

```
ABC.xyz
DEF.xyz
GHI.xyz
```

These variables are generated via a function.

At present, the "column headers" in each variable are nonsense from the output of the original function.

I would like to rename the columns in each of these variables to the first three letters of the variable name, followed by a generic suffix; say:

```
".XXX"
```

I have tried to write a quick loop that uses the function `dimnames(x)` to achieve this is as follows:

```
rename.list <- ls(pattern="*.xyz",envir=.GlobalEnv)


for (i in 1:length(rename.list)){

    dimnames(rename.list[i]) <-list(
        NULL,
        c(paste(substr(rename.list[i],0,3),".XXX",sep="")))
}
```

This produces the error:

`error in dimnames(rename.list[i]) <- list(NULL, c(paste(substr(rename.list[i], 0, 3),  : 
  'dimnames' applied to non-array`

I can see *why* this error occurs (using dimnames on rename.list is calling the name itself rather than the xts object), but not sure how to get around this. Tried using `get` etc.

Details:

R 2.13
Win 7
Package 'xts' loaded.

Many thanks in advance for any help (or suggestions to avoid the loop at all!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `assign`:

```
tmp <- get(rename.list[i])
names(tmp) <- ...
assign(rename.list[i], tmp, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: (future googlers - if it's not clear, put those 3 lines above inside of the OP's loop.)