# Why and where are \n newline characters getting introduced to c()?

Tags: r, text

Hoping someone can help me understand why errant \n characters are showing up in a vector of strings that I'm creating in R.

Trying to import and clean up a very wide data file that's in fixed width format
(http://www.state.nj.us/education/schools/achievement/2012/njask6/, 'Text file for data runs').  Followed the [UCLA tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/STAT/r/modules/raw_data.htm) on using read.fwf and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815075/fixing-dimnamesx-of-xts-objects-in-r-via-loop) excellent SO question to give the columns names after import.

Because the file is really wide, the column headers are LONG - all together, just under 29,800 characters.  I'm passing them in as a simple vector of strings:

```
column_names <- c(...)
```

I'll spare you the ugly dump here but I dropped the whole thing on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FbkNvqGt).

Was cleaning up and transforming some of the variables for analysis when I noticed that some of my subsets were returning 0 rows.  After puzzling over it (did I misspell something?) it realized that somehow a bunch of '\n' newline characters had been introduced into my column headers.

If I loop over the column_names vector that I created

```
for (i in 1:length(column_names)) {
  print(column_names[i])
}
```

I see the first newline character in the middle of the 81st line -

> SPECIAL\nEDUCATION SCIENCE Number Enrolled Science

Avenues that I tried to resolve this:

1) Is it something about my environment?  I'm using the regular script editor in R, and my lines *do* wrap - but the breaks on my screen don't match the placement of the \n characters, which to me suggests that it's not the R script editor.

2) Is there a GUI setting?  Did some [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=r%20GUI%20settings%20word%20wrap), but couldn't find anything.

3) Is there a pattern?  Seems like the newline characters get inserted about every 4000 characters.  Did some reading on R/S primitives to try to figure out if this had something to do with basic R data structures, but was pretty quickly in over my head.

I tried breaking up the long string into [shorter chunks](http://pastebin.com/k51JHjNw), and then subsequently combining them, and that seemed to solve the problem.

```
column_names.1 <- c(...)
column_names.2 <- c(...)
column_names_combined <- c(column_names.1, column_names.2)
```

so I have an immediate workaround, but would love to know what's actually going on here.

Some of the [posts](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-January/151380.html) that had to do with problems with character vectors suggested that I run memory profile:

```
  memory.profile()
        NULL      symbol    pairlist     closure environment     promise 
           1        9572      220717        4734        1379        5764 
    language     special     builtin        char     logical     integer 
       63932         165        1550       18935       10302       30428 
      double     complex   character         ...         any        list 
        2039           1       60058           0           0       20059 
  expression    bytecode externalptr     weakref         raw          S4 
           1       16553         725         150         151        1162
```

I'm running R 2.15.1 (64-bit) R on Windows 7 (Enterprise, SP 1, 8 gigs RAM).
Thanks!

Comment: How are you executing the code in the pastebin? Are you copying and pasting it? Or sourcing it from a file? Or some other way?

Comment: New script and then copying and pasting, yeah.  Not sourcing from a file.

Comment: This is a copy and paste bug in (I think) R (or perhaps the R client you are using) - just source it from a file instead.

Comment: @hadley: it looks like documented behavior, not a bug.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I think documented behaviour in R can still be a bug ;)

Comment: @hadley: sure it can, but doing so in this instance is silly.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich the bug is that it silently fails, not the limitation of the underlying data structure

Comment: @hadley I guess we have different definitions of "fails".  The _introduction_ says that one of two things will happen if you enter more than 4095 bytes of input at the console.  Would you consider signed integer overflow a bug?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Yes, I would consider silent signed integer overflow a bug, and indeed R protects you from that: `.Machine$integer.max + 1`. Silently adding newlines into user input, even if documented, is extremely undesirable behaviour.

Comment: @hadley: sorry, I was thinking of signed integer overflow in C, which is undefined and not an error (for anyone reading: hadley's example works, but I think he meant `.Machine$integer.max+1L`, which is an error).  I agree that it's very undesirable behavior and would be great to have fixed, but I'm not going to call something a "bug" when the introductory manual says "hey, if you do this, weird things will happen".

Comment: @joshuaulrich calling it a bug is probably too strong but this is certainly an extremely confusing behaviour, especially since most people don't read the intro manual.

Comment: Really appreciate the thoughtful responses - learned something new about R, and hopefully with SO's google-juice will solve this for someone else in the future.  I am sympathetic to the 'do your homework/read the manual' POV but even when you do read the manual this limitation is not exactly memorable.

Comment: The desired behavior, at least from my perspective, would be to throw a warning message just like R does when it introduces NAs or makes some other change to underlying data.  Introducing characters quietly is confusing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I doubt this is a bug.  Instead, it looks like you're running into a known limitation of the console.  As it says in [Section 1.8 - R commands, case sensitivity, etc.](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc) of [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html):

> Command lines entered at the console are limited[3] to about 4095 bytes (not characters).
>
> [3] some of the consoles will not allow you to enter more, and amongst those which do some will silently discard the excess and some will use it as the start of the next line.

Either put the command in a file and `source` it, or break the code into multiple lines by inserting your own newlines at appropriate points (between commas).  For example:

```
column_names <-
  c("County Code/DFG/Aggregation Code", "District Code", "School Code",
    "County Name", "District Name", "School Name", "DFG", "Special Needs",
    "TOTAL POPULATION TOTAL POPULATION Number Enrolled LAL", ...)
```

Comment: Fantastic - appreciate it.  Anyone with more insight into R/S know why 4095 bytes is the limitation?  Is it limitations of the data structure being used to store/house the console? An intentional design decision?

Comment: @Andrew: it's hard-coded in `src/include/Defn.h` : `#define CONSOLE_BUFFER_SIZE 4096`, so it's a limitation of the data structure.