# Dataframe with more than 200 columns

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to create a dataframe using code with the basic structure:

```
df <- data.frame(A = "a", B = "b", C = "c", D = "d", E = "e")
```

However once I go over 200 columns the code fails to finish reading, with a result something like this:

```
#complete code
#+
""
#Error: unexpected string constant in:
#(part of my code here)
#"""
```

I've rigorously checked my code for typos (which there are none) and no matter what section of the code I delete it starts to work once the number of columns goes under 200.

Any suggestions on how to make a dataframe with more than 200 columns?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Downvote for lack of any code that would demonstrate the concern. There might be a limit on the number of columns but it's far greater than 200.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize empty data frame (lot of columns at the same time) in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501345/how-to-initialize-empty-data-frame-lot-of-columns-at-the-same-time-in-r)

Comment: I am working with data that is under ethical approval so cannot reproduce my code here and have tried to include a simplified example as the data is extremely complex, hence over 200 columns but I will in future try to include better working examples.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting to the R command line? If so, it could just be that the text breaks after a certain number of characters. Try putting your text into a file, call it `import.R` or something and then do `source("import.R")`. This is a known issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216480/paste-character-limit

Comment: That fixes it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
DF <- data.frame(A = "a")

for (i in 2:300){
  DF[[paste0("V", i)]] <- runif(1)
}

ncol(DF)
# [1] 300
```

I would actually probably do this using `setDT` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

DF <- setDF(lapply(integer(300), function(...) runif(10)))
ncol(DF)
# [1] 300
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a `data.frame` with 200 columns :

```
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, as.list(1:200)))
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChirico