# Limitation on number of items in c() function in R

Tags: r

There seems to be a limit to number of items that can be included in c() function in R (100 items).
Is there any way to evade this limitation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't think that's true.. can you provide an example?  :)

Comment: My guess is that this is a duplicate of these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13059083/271616, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13216480/271616

Comment: `dput(do.call(c, as.list(rep(letters, length.out=1e3))))` works fine

Comment: Dup. And -1 for minimal effort. Search on: [r] maximum length vector: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640836/max-length-for-a-vector-in-r

Answer (score 4):

There is a limit, but it is a limit of vector length, not a limitation of `c`:

```
length(eval(call('c', 1:(2^31-1))))
## [1] 2147483647

length(eval(call('c', 1:(2^31))))
## Error in 1:(2^31) : result would be too long a vector
```

Comment: I think R 3.0 (or whatever version number they end up using) overcomes the 2^31 - 1 index limit

Comment: I'm going to need more memory.  `1:(2^31-1)` takes 25% of my RAM, and `1:(2^31-1)+.5` takes 75%.