# R read string too long

Tags: python, r, rpython

Hi I have a string generated by Python and I need to read into R to analyze it.

The only difference between the two strings below is the length(number of elements inside list). And R cannot read the longer one successfully.

```
textWork <- "[('08/10/2013 01:50:16 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/10/2013 02:04:23 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/11/2013 02:29:46 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/12/2013 12:58:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/12/2013 01:12:18 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/13/2013 01:14:57 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/14/2013 02:01:42 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/14/2013 02:04:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/15/2013 01:09:23 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/15/2013 01:22:50 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/16/2013 12:56:52 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/16/2013 01:09:38 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/17/2013 12:54:20 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/17/2013 01:07:51 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/18/2013 12:54:14 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/18/2013 01:09:37 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/19/2013 12:54:13 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/19/2013 01:10:06 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/20/2013 02:09:17 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/20/2013 02:25:56 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/21/2013 01:21:03 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/21/2013 01:34:59 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/22/2013 01:32:54 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/22/2013 01:55:25 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/23/2013 01:23:44 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/23/2013 01:41:08 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/24/2013 01:17:46 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/24/2013 01:31:12 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/25/2013 12:57:21 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/25/2013 01:10:55 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/26/2013 12:56:37 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/26/2013 01:11:03 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/27/2013 01:00:15 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/27/2013 01:13:09 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/28/2013 01:07:21 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/28/2013 01:24:13 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/29/2013 12:57:08 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/29/2013 01:10:57 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/30/2013 12:56:22 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/30/2013 01:10:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/31/2013 12:53:37 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/31/2013 01:08:01 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/01/2013 12:52:11 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/01/2013 01:06:40 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/02/2013 12:50:31 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/02/2013 01:05:16 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/03/2013 12:54:07 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/03/2013 01:09:32 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/04/2013 01:16:11 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/05/2013 12:59:34 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/06/2013 12:55:00 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/07/2013 01:13:40 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/09/2013 01:07:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1')]"

textNotWork <- "[('08/10/2013 01:50:16 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/10/2013 02:04:23 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/11/2013 02:29:46 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/12/2013 12:58:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/12/2013 01:12:18 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/13/2013 01:14:57 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/10/2013 01:50:16 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/10/2013 02:04:23 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/11/2013 02:29:46 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/12/2013 12:58:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/12/2013 01:12:18 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/13/2013 01:14:57 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/10/2013 01:50:16 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/10/2013 02:04:23 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/11/2013 02:29:46 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/12/2013 12:58:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/12/2013 01:12:18 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/13/2013 01:14:57 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/10/2013 01:50:16 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/10/2013 02:04:23 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/11/2013 02:29:46 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/12/2013 12:58:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/12/2013 01:12:18 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/13/2013 01:14:57 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/14/2013 02:01:42 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/14/2013 02:04:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/15/2013 01:09:23 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/15/2013 01:22:50 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/16/2013 12:56:52 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/16/2013 01:09:38 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/17/2013 12:54:20 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/17/2013 01:07:51 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/18/2013 12:54:14 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/18/2013 01:09:37 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/19/2013 12:54:13 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/19/2013 01:10:06 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/20/2013 02:09:17 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/20/2013 02:25:56 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/21/2013 01:21:03 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/21/2013 01:34:59 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/22/2013 01:32:54 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/22/2013 01:55:25 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/23/2013 01:23:44 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/23/2013 01:41:08 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/24/2013 01:17:46 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/24/2013 01:31:12 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/25/2013 12:57:21 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/25/2013 01:10:55 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/26/2013 12:56:37 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/26/2013 01:11:03 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/27/2013 01:00:15 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/27/2013 01:13:09 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/28/2013 01:07:21 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/28/2013 01:24:13 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/29/2013 12:57:08 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/29/2013 01:10:57 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/30/2013 12:56:22 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/30/2013 01:10:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/31/2013 12:53:37 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('08/31/2013 01:08:01 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/01/2013 12:52:11 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/01/2013 01:06:40 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/02/2013 12:50:31 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/02/2013 01:05:16 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/03/2013 12:54:07 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/03/2013 01:09:32 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/04/2013 01:16:11 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/05/2013 12:59:34 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/06/2013 12:55:00 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/07/2013 01:13:40 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1'), ('09/09/2013 01:07:43 AM INFO', 'product1', '', '61.12000', '1')]"
```

[image]

Question(1) As you can see, this is a list of tuple in Python, and the original data(textNotWork) actually contains more tuple elements (string was longer), and I cannot read the text successfully. Anyone know what is really going on?  How can I read a string that is pretty long.

Question(2) How can I turn that into a dataframe with five variables (seems like one variable is an empty string) dataframe in R so I can turn that into a time series and analyze it.

Thanks

Comment: It works on my R 3.0.1 on a Windows 7 box. What is the R version you are using?

Comment: looks like a known limitation of the console. save the text in a file and source it.

Comment: I see the edit now. That plus sign probably signifies that something is missing from the character string. Typically there is a mismatch of quotes, brackets or square brackets.

Comment: Saving to a text file would probaby be an easy solution, if you can write the string to the disk from Python.

Comment: @JTT My R version is 3.0.1, and I am 100% sure that is no brackets or quote missing in that string. You can copy the textWork and simply add more elements to it (maybe 20 tuples?) and it will show the plus sign.

Comment: @JTT I am actually reading from standard input by line from a plain text file, which is generated by Python. And when I read a line and pass to R as a string, this problem pop up.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13059083/271616

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.  I'm running 3.0.1 on linux, and it works fine.  `nchar(textnotWork)` is equal to `4686`.

Comment: The limit is on bytes, not on characters. Some characters might take more than one byte to store, but the answer to the question should be based on a solution to circumvent the limit. @agstudy actually has one nice possibility charted out below now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea to transform your python structures(I think that the solution given here is general for any python structure) is to save them(using python) as a json format and read them after using R. So you can do something like this:

### python

```
textNotWork = [('08/10/2013 01:50:16 AM INFO', ...]
with open("testing.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(textNotWork,file)
```

### R

```
library(rjson)
matrix(unlist(fromJSON(file='testing.json')),
          ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)

 [1,] "08/10/2013 01:50:16 AM INFO" "product1" ""   "61.12000" "1" 
 [2,] "08/10/2013 02:04:23 AM INFO" "product1" ""   "61.12000" "1" 
 [3,] "08/11/2013 02:29:46 AM INFO" "product1" ""   "61.12000" "1" 
 [4,] "08/12/2013 12:58:43 AM INFO" "product1" ""   "61.12000" "1"
```

Comment: Actually, I want to print the json type output to the standard output instead of a specific file. Do you know how to do it?