# Rscript appears to have a length limit. Options to circumvent it?

Tags: r, knitr, rscript, nanoc

I want to pass arbitrarily long strings to `Rscript -e`.  However, there appears to be a length limit.

Consider the pattern:

```
$ Rscript -e 'cat("some string goes here")'
```

If the string has a length of 9993 (on my machine), the command fails and hangs indefinitely.  If it has a length of 9992, it outputs the string as I desire.  (Your numbers may be different; you can do a binary search to find them if you're so inclined.)  The failure looks like this:

```
WARNING: '-e cat("hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi!hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
```

(Note that the string is truncated in exactly this same way in my console: this input string is *not* the **full** input string.  This also means that I know there's a `WARNING`, but I don't know what it's warning me about!)

What is a good way to get around this limitation?  I *could* stick the content in a temp file under `/tmp`, but that strikes me as too messy.

What I'm really looking to do is to use `Rscript` (specifically, `knitr`) as a text filter: old string goes in, new string comes out.

For reference, here is [my first iteration of this filter](https://github.com/chiphogg/chogg_name/commit/9196358).  The problem is that when the input becomes too large, `nanoc` hangs indefinitely.  (I now know this is because `Rscript` is hanging; hence, this question.)

Comment: It's a [limitation of the console](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13060979/271616). Trying dumping the string to a temporary file and pass the file to `Rscript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of readline (or whatever function is doing duty for stdin), not Rscript or R. If you don't want to follow Joshua's advice to source from a file then you will need to rewrite your system's input program.